# Suppress a warning in lsp-mode using clangd

Tags: flycheck, lsp-mode, warning, clang

Here's an example of code for which I get a warning when using lsp-mode, with clangd:

```
struct A {
  union {
    struct B {
       int i;
    } b;
  };
};
```

The warning appears with a flycheck mark on the left, telling me that types cannot be declared in an anonymous union. I would like to suppress this error, but I can't seem to figure out how. How can I suppress a clangd warning from within lsp-mode?